# How can I use Angular-promise-tracker with factories?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use Angular-promise-tracker with services called from a factory. I am almost sure I am not doing it in the right way... because it does not work.

My need : creating a service for managing a gif 'currently loading' like.

Here I have defined a factory for storing my promise states:

```
    angular.module('fusseApp.services.loadTrack', ['ajoslin.promise-tracker'])

.factory('loadTrackFactory', ['promiseTracker', function(promiseTracker){

    var tracker = null;
    var trackerService = {};

    trackerService.giveMeSomeTrack = function(){
        tracker = promiseTracker('Loading');
    };

    trackerService.getTracker = function(){
        return tracker; 
    }

    return trackerService;

}]);
```

Here is my main controller :

```
.controller('MainCtrl',     ['$scope','$location','authenticationFactory','notificationService','loadTrackFactory',
        function ($scope, $location, authentication, notificationService, loadTrackFactory) {

$scope.loadTracker = loadTrackFactory.getTracker(); 

        }]);
```

I have a template included inside a div with my main controller :

```
  <div ng-show="loadTracker.active()" style="color: red; font-size: 50px;">
    Loading!
  </div>
```

And I am trying to use my service here :

```
fusseApp.factory('ArticleFactory'
    , ['$http', 'URI', 'notificationService', 'loadTrackFactory', '$timeout'
    , function ($http, URI, notificationService, loadTrackFactory, $timeout) {
    return {
        getArticleInfos: function (idEntrepot, codeArticle, callback) {

            **loadTrackFactory.giveMeSomeTrack();**

            $http.get(URI.GET_ARTICLE_URI + '?idEntrepot=' + idEntrepot
                    + '&codeArticle=' + codeArticle, 
                    {tracker: 'Loading'} //Pour le "chargement en cours"
                    ).
                success(function (data, status) {
                    if (status === 204) {
                        notificationService.pushInfo("Article introuvable.");
                    }
                    callback(data);
                });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Why does your loadTrackFactory just create tracker and just return it. What do you need the giveMeSomeTrack() and getTracker() methods for?

Comment: Yes you are right. But it does not solve my problem. Actually I finished by not using a service because it is to much complex (surrounding all my services call with a promise just for displaying a "loading gif" !?).  I just created my promise tracker in my ctrl and resolve it in the success or error callbacks.